Coud not create MoklistRT and other errors
I'm absolutely new in Linux.
I installed Ubuntu on my machine. Then I got the error on the image.

I solved it by deleting the keys and restore default ones, but here's the twist. Every time I boot up the computer I have this error and I need to boot it on the BIOS and repeat the key deleting/reinstall process.
The computer boots up, but then it displays another error:
EFI stub: WARNING: Failed to measure data for event 1:800000000000000b
After this I'm in. When I'm in I can't access the SSDs and I'm getting issues installing apps like Nordvpn (waiting for cache lock: could not find lock and it just loads forever.)
If I delete Windows from the Linux terminal and give all the partition to Ubuntu afterwards would this be a good idea?
